# Win10 desktop link protection GPO does not work

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, desktop, group-policy

We set up a GPO for RD-Users as following:

```
user config
- guidelines
-- administrative templates
--- desktop
---- desktop
----- don't allow changes ON
----- don't allow adding of elements ON
----- don't allow deleting of elements ON
----- don't allow editing of elements ON
--- control panel
---- adaption
----- don't allow changes of desktopsymbols ON
```

If i log in with that user and export all GPOs affecting him. The GPO is active, but somehow the user can still edit the links, add new ones, copy objekts onto the desktop or delete items. Just as if no GPO was active. Anybody got an idea why the GPO doesn't work?

Comment: Has the GPO been applied (what does GPRESULT tell you)?

Comment: I run it several times and every time it told me it has been applied. But still we were able to manipulate the desktop items nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the settings within the policy at User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Desktop > Desktop.

1. "Prohibit Changes" has the following descriptive text,

   > Requirements: Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000 only

   Unless you're running one of those systems (and if so, why!?) it's not applicable.
2. "Prohibit adding/deleting/editing items" has the same descriptive text,

   > Requirements: Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000 only

   Unless you're running one of those systems it's not applicable.

Considering the settings within the policy at User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization.

1. "Prevent changing desktop icons". This prevents the user from changing the icon symbols themselves. It does not restrict the adding, removing, or editing of entries on the Desktop.

I don't have an elegant solution to prevent users from adding their own icons to the Desktop, but you can disallow edits and deletes of existing icons for accounts that are not local administrators by placing these desktop icons in the Public Desktop rather than each user's Desktop.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the last part. 

"Prevent changing desktop icons" is what i ment with this (which i translated manually as i don't have an English installation:
--- control panel
---- adaption
----- don't allow changes of desktopsymbols ON

Comment: @tmo, I was fairly sure you'd translated to English for us - thank you. I provided the English names for the GPO paths so you could be comfortable I was looking in the same place as you.

Comment: Thanks. To my regret we got more than one user on the machine, which do not have the same links on the desktop. So i need another idea.

Comment: Permissions/ownership of the Desktop folder itself, inherited by the icons placed there?

Comment: Those setting prevent adding desktop gadgets to the Active Desktop. They were html pages embedded into the desktop and underneath icons. It was replaced by the sidebar which was replaced by the live tiles on the start menu.